# Is it possible to make these functions shorter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create there three functions. I'm thinking of making it shorter or combine into one function. Is it possible?
Here is my code!

```
$(function(){
   $(".js-disable-form").on("submit", function() {
     $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
     $(this).find("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
   })
});

$(function(){
  $(".js-disable-form-approval").on("submit", function() { 
    var res = confirm("入力内容で承認します。よろしいですか？");
    if (res == true) {
      $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
      $(this).find("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
     return false;
      }
    })
});

$(function(){
  $(".js-disable-form-individual").on("submit", function() {
    $(this).find("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
  })
  $('.js-disable-btn').on("click", function() { 
    $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
  })  
});
```

Comment: perhaps you should explain what your functions are?

Comment: Instead of just pasting the code, explain what it does, what you have tried, and what should be the expected result.

Comment: When I submit the form I want to trigger modal and also disabled submit button. Depend on difference situations trigger there two events. So I mafe there three functions

Comment: Try on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function showModal() { $('#loading-modal').modal('show'); }

function disableSubmit() { $(".js-disable-form input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true); }

$(function() {
  $(".js-disable-form").on("submit", function() {
    showModal();
    disableSubmit();
  });

  $(".js-disable-form-approval").on("submit", function() {
    if (confirm("入力内容で承認します。よろしいですか？")) {
      showModal();
      disableSubmit();
    } else return false;
  });

  $(".js-disable-form-individual").on("submit", disableSubmit);
  $('.js-disable-btn').on("click", showModal);
});
```

This isn't much shorter than the original code but should show how to avoid duplicate code in general.

Comment: Thank you! It looks more cleaner now.

Answer (score 0):

You could at least put all event handlers into one function:

```
$(function(){
    $(".js-disable-form").on("submit", function() {
        $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
        $(this).find("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
    })

    $(".js-disable-form-approval").on("submit", function() { 
        var res = confirm("入力内容で承認します。よろしいですか？");
        if (res == true) {
            $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
            $(this).find("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    })

    $(".js-disable-form-individual").on("submit", function() {
        $(this).find("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
    })

    $('.js-disable-btn').on("click", function() { 
        $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
    })  
});
```

Comment: I agree with you. At least  put all event handlers into one function!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[class^=".js-disable-"').on("submit", function(){
    if ($(this).className.indexOf("individual") >= 0 || $(this).className.indexOf("form") >=0){
        $(this).find("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);  
        if ($(this).className.indexOf("individual") >= 0 ){     
            $('.js-disable-btn').on("click", function() { 
                $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
            })  
        }
        else{
            $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
        }
    }  
    else { 
        var res = confirm("入力内容で承認します。よろしいですか？");
        if (res == true) {
            $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
            $(this).find("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Didn't test since there's no html attached. Basicly it matches the classes that starts with .js-disable- and attaches a submit event. Then it's just reranging of your functions.

Comment: Your code is beautiful. But It's not fit my level now.